# How to configure TomEE 1.5.2 to only offer SSL cipher suites considered trusted/safe nowadays?

Tags: ssl, apache-tomee

I am getting this error in FF when I try to reach my application.

> (Error code: ssl_error_weak_server_ephemeral_dh_key)

I was following this [HOW TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Certificates) on configuring SSL, but it does not work. So how to configure TomEE?

What I did was generate keystore:

`keytool -genkeypair -v -dname   "cn=NAME, ou= NEME, o= NAME, l=CITY, st=STATE, c=XX" -alias tomcat -    keypass PASS -storepass PASS -keyalg RSA -validity 3650`

And added to server.xml:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false"
        disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxThreads="25"
        port="8444" keystoreFile="KEYSTORE_FILE" keystorePass="PASS"
        protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https"
        secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing is due to Firefox's mitigation for the [Logjam attack](https://weakdh.org/) . To fix this, you'd have to increase your DH key length, which unfortunately, does not appear to be an option at this time for Tomcat or TomEE.

The options you have at this time are

a) Remove support for DH cipher suites for your server and only allow non-DH cipher suites. This is described in the [official Logjam mitigations page](https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html) (scroll down to the section titled "Apache Tomcat"). Pay close attention to the note about the action needed to use 256 bit AES ciphers.

OR

b) Disable the security settings in Firefox to allow connections to sites like yours that have weak DH keys. This is not advisable as your users may not be willing to decrease their security just to access your site. This is described in a related [Security Stack Exchange answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/93118/72313).